# How to configure Illustrator in mm?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, units

When I create a new document, everything is showed in `Points` not in `mm` despite that I have configured Illustrator to use `mm` instead of `inches`:

[image]

How can I change that ?

Comment: looking at that screenshot, right there in the new document settings it's in Points. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: Yeah I can select `mm` but when I restart my program, I have the same issue.

Comment: You're selecting a preset, as its name said, it will always come with that configuration. I think it's better you create a file with all your configurations and save it as a template.